# How do I make a c# exe artificially large?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to make an existing c# app 10MB in size.

Making the app is easy, making it large intentionally, not so much. There is the obvious way of adding embedded images, but I want the exe to compress to a small size as well. Any idea?

Comment: You cannot be serious. Are you? I must know why.

Comment: Why on earth would you need an executable to be 10mb large when it doesn't have to be? That's the most ludicrous thing I've ever heard of. Unless you're tying to do some fancy replacing of files with filesize checking, this is just madness.

Comment: I can't say much, however this is a temp app (dummy) if you will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about an embedded resource that contains only whitespace? That should compress well.

Comment: Ok, that's an obvious one I missed. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 4):

Why not add an embedded resource text file of many repeated characters?